# The utf-8 characters do not appears on my app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I developed an app using frameworks like Armchair and SwiftyRadio to play music 24/7.

There's a problem though, I developed a website and when the current title is played the title appears like this, it's a m3u file that transcribes the title without any problems.

[image: Title on the website]

However on my app, the title appears like this.

[image: Title on app]

There are no dots or even brackets on the display. I tried to use the UTF-8 encoding on the right panel to see if it was an encoding problem but nothing changed. Do you have a solution? Thank you!!

Actual code :

```
    import UIKit
    import MediaPlayer
    import MarqueeLabel
    import Armchair
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
        @IBOutlet weak var songNameLabel: MarqueeLabel!

let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(presentAlertVC))
        songNameLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        songNameLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

@objc func updateView() {
        songNameLabel.text = "\(swiftyRadio.trackArtist()) - \(swiftyRadio.trackTitle())      "
```

Comment: What are you using for displaying it? Please provide actual code

Comment: edited! I forgot ^^

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you're applying utf-8 encoding. I strongly suspect that `swiftyRadio.trackTitle()` is not returning what you expect it to, and does not include the punctuation, which is why it likely isn't displaying it.

Comment: @RobNapier found the solution! thanks for the little tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay! found the solution! A little thing to add in the "SwiftyRadio" file :

```
fileprivate func clean(_ text: String) -> String {
    let safeChars : Set<Character> = Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'- []().&é§è!çà)°_$*€%ù@#£:=;?,ÉÈÀEÊêâÂÙôÔ")
    return String(text.filter { safeChars.contains($0) })
}
```

it's perfect now :)

Comment: I'm curious about this list. Is there a reason that Turkish (ı), German (ß), Hungarian (í) and other Latin-based languages should be excluded here? (Let alone non-Latin writing systems.) Is there some reason to filter characters? Why £, €, and $, but not ¥, 元, and ﷼?

Comment: iIt was not on the default list so you have to add characters like ¥, 元 or ﷼ and even more!